Why does prolog allows duplicate facts and rules in its database?
Why does prolog allows duplicate facts and rules in its database?
It is not difficult to make the addition of facts to the database idempotent. For rules it is not trivial to establish the logical equality between two rules.
Duplicate rules and facts can lead to, say, surprising, results which aren't really logically warranted. E.g.:
f(a).
f(a).
g(X) :- f(X).
g(Z) :- f(Z).
findall(Y, g(Y), Y).

Results in Y = [a,a,a,a]. Operationally speaking, this result is easy enough to understand considering Prolog's backtracking mechanism.
But, doesn't this put a strain on the declarative logical interpretation of Prolog programs?  Assuming f(a) twice doesn't make it more true! And logically speaking the ensuing result should just have been Y = [a].
Just like dropping the so-called occurs check during unification in many Prolog implementations, allowing for duplicate facts and rules could have been a performance consideration. Checking for duplicate facts wouldn't be too difficult. Checking for duplicate rules, I hypothesise, is NP-complete and would have an algorithm with  exponential complexity.
Is there a reason in the design of Prolog why they allowed duplicate facts and rules other than performance? I realise that this question harks back deep into history, but I believe that understanding this design choice helps in designing better Prolog programs.
Looking forward to the community's insights!

Prolog is a programming language, not an expert system, or a declarative logic environment, or even a database in the general sense. A programming language that doesn't let you do something is just not a good programming language. Since you can do anything you want with it, you can also implement a system where duplicate ground facts are not allowed, using the mechanism that suits your use case. I don't believe efficiency is the primary motivation here but this is an opinion.

If anything I see Prolog as an, albeit imperfect, implementation of a pure logic programming language, similar to the ones described in Robert Kowalski's "Logic for Problem Solving" and the first chapters of Sterling and Shapiro's "The Art of Prolog". My question originates from a definition in Lloyd's "Foundations of Logic Programming" where a logic program is defined as a set of program clauses (facts are just a special form of a clause).

There might be a terminology confusion, not sure. A program is a set of predicates (rules or facts); each predicate has predicate clauses but they are not a set, they are a list. Maybe see here and compare this to the text you are reading. If the terminology is subtly different we need to get that cleared up first.

It's for performance, essentially.
Prolog is all about relations - but there's no concept of a primary key, so Prolog doesn't know whether the duplicate is e.g. intentional or required.
Don't forget: Duplicates might be essential as part of the logic of the program, depending on the Developer's intentions. Same with self-referencing, which can be useful in some data structures, which is a reasonable reason for the occurs check being off by default.
It's up to the Developer to deal with duplicates.
Duplicates can be handled in code, and there's many built-ins to help, e.g. once, sort, setof, distinct.
In your example, setof would solve the problem of duplicates:
?- setof(Y, g(Y), Y).
Y = [a].

The removal of duplicates "breaks" relations, which is a good reason for the Prolog system to make no attempt by itself. For example: if we sort a list and have the result of [a], then how long was the original list? Could have been [a,a,a,a,a,a] etc., from 1 to an infinite number of as. That is awkward.
If the program has:
f(a).
f(a).

... that's a blatant duplication of ground facts. However, things are usually more subtle, with unification of partially-instantiatated variables.
As an example, to remove duplicate ground facts:
:- dynamic f/1.
f(a).
f(a).

remove_duplicate_fs :-
    bagof(f(A), f(A), Fs),
    remove_duplicate_fs_(Fs).

remove_duplicate_fs_([]).
remove_duplicate_fs_([F|Fs]) :-
    (   member(M, Fs),
        F == M
    ->  once(retract(F))
    ;   true
    ),
    remove_duplicate_fs_(Fs).

Result in swi-prolog:
?- listing(f/1).
:- dynamic f/1.

f(a).
f(a).

true.

?- remove_duplicate_fs.
true.

?- listing(f/1).
:- dynamic f/1.

f(a).

true.


An extensive answer, thanks!  But I've to contend to your suggestion that removing relations would "break" things. As I stated in the post, logical meaning of repeated facts should be the same as just assuming it once (idempotency).  In FOPL:  (∀a:: (p(a) ⋀ p(a) ≡ p(a))  ⋀ ( p(a) ⋁ p(a) ≡ p(a))  ) and therefore should not impact any inference.

BTW: Your suggestion that one would need a notion of a primary key in Prolog to be able to weed out duplicates is belied by your own example code to remove duplicates! You can model SQL very well in Prolog, but not vice versa, I would say.

@nanitous I don't understand your points. It's perfectly possible to have duplicate rows in a SQL table - whether that it undesired, depends on the data and its intended usage. My example code to remove duplicates is using ==, and is nothing to do with a primary key. Data can have duplicates. Yes, is seems pointless to have duplicate ground facts. But Prolog doesn't distinguish between facts and data. It's up to the Developer to make that distinction and add whatever safeguards desired in the code.

I've added a couple of improvements to my answer.

"It's for performance, essentially" misses the point by a lot. Since this is a "why" question I will not bother answering it on SO, just sharing my opinion with you.

@TA_intern true, a little inaccuracy saves more explanation. I'd welcome an answer which elaborates on e.g. that.

@TA_intern Although it is a "why" question, I only asked for the possible consequences when designing Prolog programs. One of the possible consequences I used as an example. I gather that duplicate facts and rules are as "unlogical" as the Prolog cut predicate is.
